# How to disable editing some tag in block of tags that ending tag is modified automatically?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

Working with PhpStorm ( version 2021.2 ) sometimes I found it very
inconvenient when editing some tag in block of tags that ending tag is modified automatically. Say when modifying tag `<section>` into `</div>`.

1. Is there an option to disable this behavior?
2. Maybe preferable way is to disable this behavior temporary, say when holding some hot key?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an option to disable this behavior?

Sure:

1. `Settings (Preferences on macOS)`
2. `Editor | General | Smart Keys`
3. `HTML/CSS | Simultaneous '<tag></tag>' editing`

[image]

> Say when modifying tag `<section>` into `</div>`.

I see no problem with such editing. Section has the closing `</section>` tag so the IDE just edits both places at the same time (from `section` to `div`).

Unless you have a broken HTML (not balanced open/closing tags) already...

> Maybe preferable way is to disable this behavior temporary, say when holding some hot key?

No. But if you disable the aforementioned option then you can still edit both open and closing tag at once -- just manually invoke `Refactor | Rename` on it.

[image]